# Combination of different Shimano braking components

Tags: brakes, shimano

For a daily city bike i want to combine some older Shimano Components.

Is it possible to combine a Shimano XT V-Brake Lever (BL-M739) with a Shimano 105 SLR Front brake or are there any things i have to pay attention to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V-Brakes and calliper brakes operate with different lengths of cable being pulled.

V-Brake levers pull a lot more cable and in this set up, your lever throw will be too sort to be usable and have very little stopping power.

[Sheldon, as usual, has more.](http://sheldonbrown.com/canti-direct.html#levers)

You can get [adapters](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/travel_agents) to go the other way, road levers with v-brakes, but I've never seen one go this way.

Your best bet would be to look for some flat bar levers for the calliper brakes you have. Almost any [sold as a road lever](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/nl/index/components/road/flat_handlebar0.html) should work.

Comment: A lot of these parts are sold for "flat bar road bikes", though note that getting a new flat bar lever is more expensive than a set of v brakes.

Comment: Note you can also pull some old short pull brake levers from an old parts bin at your LBS/Co-op which should work (provided the age of the (super) SLR unit - IIRC some have some weird lever requirements in which case, check the manual for the particular brake.)

Comment: Bit hair-brained tonight and can't edit comments, but you can just wire a travel agent in reverse to do this as well (forward being short pull levers with long pull brakes, reverse being long pull levers with short pull brakes), but the price would also be as expensive as getting the right levers (travel agents aren't free). Just note that the additional cable stress of a travel agent on the cable isn't necessarily a good thing (they can fray cables).

Comment: To be fair, new levers aren't prohibitively expensive, nor are they hard to come by. http://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/index.php?category=1594 Additionally, used levers from canti-equipped mtbs are pretty ubiquitous.

Comment: @Batman I think the travel agents are road levers to v-brake only. There's a little compatibility table at the  bottom of that page. (Linear pull = v-brake).

Comment: @alex - Its not a common problem people want to solve usually (very few people have v brake levers but want to run canti's or calipers), so its not worth mentioning - getting v brakes or a set of short pull levers is a cheaper/better idea. However, if you wire the travel agent one way to double the pull, wiring it in reverse will half the pull (and since travel agents don't change work, the forces work out appropriately - fwd = short pull -> long pull, reverse = long pull -> short pull). You can try it at your own risk, of course or rig up a small pulley and play with it to verify.

Comment: That being said, QBP probably doesn't condone this use, and the positioning of the barrel adjuster isn't quite right for this application anyway so you may want to add another one for that. But its just a Physics 101 pulley problem at the end of the day ignoring mounting of the travel agent + barrel adjuster issues.